# Assembly program carriage return won't output correctly

Tags: assembly, output, newline, carriage-return, dosbox

so I have an assignment in my assembly language class, a fairly simple one, but for some reason, the CR, or 13, isn't working properly and I can't seem to figure out why. I'm fairly new at this, but I have used CR, 13, in previous programs before and it's worked fine before. For the sake of simplicity, I added a test output before the instructions of the program just to show how the carriage return isn't working with just 2 strings of text (the test string and the instruction string). (mind you, I still tried running the program in this simplified form and the carriage return still won't work)

This is my code:

```
INCLUDE PCMAC.INC
.model small
.stack 100
.data
CR EQU 13
TestW db "THIS IS A TEST!$", CR
Instruct db "This program will average numbers entered until you type [q]. $", CR

.code
NumAverage PROC
mov ax, @data ;address of start data
mov ds, ax ;second part

_PutStr TestW ;TEMPORARY STRING

_PutStr Instruct ;instruction prompt

_Exit
NumAverage ENDP ;end main procedure
END NumAverage ;start execution
```

Because of the course I'm in, I'm to strictly use the software they give, which is Notepad++ for the coding, assembling and linking is in the windows command prompt, and masm615/DOSBox v0.74 for running the program.

At first I assumed it just wasn't assembling or linking correctly or for some reason it was "stuck" on a previous version of me writing the code, but it would still update when I saved the code and changed the text, yet nothing would change with the carriage return. I also tried using LF, or 10, alone and simultaneously after the strings like:

`TestW db "THIS IS A TEST!$", CR, LF`

And still the problem persisted. Am I missing something entirely? Or is there just a little mistake I made that I can't see? (I'm still very new to this so bear with me)

Also a visual of the output I get when running the program:
[Output reads: C:\BIN>numave~2..."THIS IS A TEST!This program will average numbers entered until you type [q]."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUQwh.png)

Comment: You put the `$` in the wrong place. That signals the end of string so whatever else you put after is not going to be printed. Try `TestW db "THIS IS A TEST!", CR, LF, "$"` instead.

Comment: @Jester oml, tysm, I think this issue before on one of my first programs but I completely forgot, this makes so much sense now. I knew it was gonna be something so simple too